# New variable in a convex optimization problem

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the convex optimization program
$$ \min_{x \in X } x^\top P x + p^\top x \quad \text{ sub. to: } Ax = b $$
where $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact, $P \succ 0$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. Let $x^*$ be the optimizer.

Now consider the convex optimization program
$$ \min_{x \in X, y \in \mathbb{R}^m } x^\top P x + p^\top x + \alpha\left\| y-b\right\|^2 \quad \text{ sub. to: } Ax = y $$
where $\alpha > 0$ is a parameter to be chosen. Let $(x_{\alpha}^*, y_{\alpha}^*)$ be the optimizer.

I am wondering about $\left\| x^* - x_{\alpha}^*\right\|$ for large $\alpha$. I am not sure it is true that $\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty}\left\| x^* - x_{\alpha}^*\right\| = 0$.

Comment: I'm curious why this was voted down. Would the voter care to share why? (It's one thing not to vote on it *at all*; but to vote it down with no comment seems unfortunate. It seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. Seems someone has personal matters to downvote my questions. My last one got -17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly equivalent (in all the respects that matter to us here) to
$$\begin{array}{ll}\text{minimize} & x^T P x + p^T x + \alpha \| A x - b \|^2\end{array}$$
Now, this is actually a well-studied approach to solving constrained problems. The term $\|Ax-b\|_2^2$ is a *penalty function*. I encourage you to do a literature search to learn about the theoretical details.

Yes, it is indeed true that $x^*_\alpha\rightarrow x^*$ as $\alpha\rightarrow \infty$. But in fact, there is a more interesting question: is $x^*_\alpha=x^*$ for some *finite* value of $\alpha$ (and larger)? It turns out that *no*, the squared-norm penalty is what is called an *inexact* penalty function, and there is no finite value of $\alpha$ for which $A x^*_\alpha=b$ (in general; there might be for certain specific values of $P$, $p$, $A$, $b$).

On the other hand, consider the following alternative:
$$\begin{array}{ll}\text{minimize} & x^T P x + p^T x + \alpha \| A x - b \|_1\end{array}$$
notice that we have eliminated the square, and are using the sum-of-absolute-values norm $\|\cdot\|_1$. This is an *exact* penalty function, which means that for some *finite* value of $\alpha$ (and larger), you will get $x_\alpha^*=x^*$. Of course, it's also not differentiable anymore :-) There's no free lunch.

Again, please read the literature on penalty functions to see a formal development. You will have to trust me that introducing the new variable $y$ and the accompanying equality constraint does *not* change anything I have said here.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've made the edit.